# Handling promises in Ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a service which handles user authentication. The `auth` service that gets user details from database .

```
getUser(){
  return this.storage.get('user').then( (user) => {
    if (user){
       this.user = user;
       return user
    } 
}
```

And in the component I get the user like,

```
  public user ;
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.auth.getUser().then( (user) => {
      this.user = user;
    })
    .catch( (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

And in the html page I have `{{ user.uid }}` where uid is an attribute of the `user` object. But I get an error in the console,

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./Home class Home - inline template:9:21 caused by: self.context.user is undefined ; 

Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { _nativeError: Error, originalError: TypeError, context: Object, stack: "" } anonymous/_View_Home0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@Home.ngfactory.js:153:7
```

The user object will be resolved only after the promise get resolved. The user is not defined untill then. How can I resolve this issue. I do not want to use `async` with a promise return as I want to handle `error` catching in component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *elvis operator* in your view, so if the `user` property is still null, Angular won't try to access the `uid` property.

`{{ user?.uid }}`

Comment: Thanks man. That helped. Would be better if there is some documentation on this.

Comment: Glad I could help :)